# Image only being made smaller by \includegraphics [scale...]

Tags: graphics, resize, scale

Working in rmarkdown. This is my YAML:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

I have one image that I would like to increase the size of as the font inside is small:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{no_contraction.jpg}
\caption {Regulation of vascular smooth muscle relaxation by Nitric Oxide \\ Image taken from Griffiths and Evans, 2005}
\label{f:no_contraction}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

This is how it appears:
[image: Unscaled image]

So I have tried to scale the image:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{no_contraction.jpg}
\caption {Regulation of vascular smooth muscle relaxation by Nitric Oxide \\ Image taken from Griffiths and Evans, 2005}
\label{f:no_contraction}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

However, whatever number I put for the scale, it is making the image tiny:
[image: Scaled image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: That is a very strange one. I hardly ever use `scale=` as it is rather subjective, try `width=0.9\textwidth` instead.

Comment: Unrelated, don't use the `center` env to center inside a figure env, they both add vertical spacing. Replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`